# Replace first 7 lines of one file with content of another file

Tags: text-processing

I've two files. One is called `file1.txt` and the other is `person1.txt`. Both of them contain some lines of text as in the following example:

- `file1.txt`

  ```
  word1
  word2
  word3
  word4
  word5
  word6
  word7
  word8
  word9
  ```
- `person1.txt`

  ```
  givi sixarulidze
  ```

What I want to do is to replace first seven lines of code in `file1.txt` with the content of `person1.txt`.

- Desired output:

  ```
  givi sixarulidze
  word8
  word9
  ```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you researched the answers here or done research via Google to find a solution?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `person1.txt` has less then seven lines? What should the preferred solution do if `person1.txt` is longer?

Answer (score 14):

```
cp person1.txt result.txt
tail -n+8 file1 >> result.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

Using GNU `sponge` to do in-place editing of `file1.txt`:

```bash
{ cat person1.txt; tail -n +8 file1.txt; } | sponge file1.txt
```

This concatenates the `person1.txt` file with all but the 7 first lines from the `file1.txt` file and saves the result into `file1.txt`.

With `sed`, you would do the same with

```bash
sed -e '1r person1.txt' -e '1,7d' file1.txt | sponge file1.txt
```

(you could use `8,$!d` in place of `1,7d`), or, if using GNU `sed`,

```bash
sed -i -e '1r person1.txt' -e '1,7d' file1.txt
```

This inserts the contents of `person1.txt` at the start and then skips the first seven lines from the `file1.txt` input file.

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility is `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR || FNR>7' person1.txt file1.txt > result.txt
```

This will process first `person1.txt` and then `file1.txt`. It will print the current line if either

- we are processing the first of the two files, where `NR` (the global line-counter)  is equal to `FNR`, the per-file line counter, *or*
- the per-file line-counter is larger than 7 (which will only be a limitation when processing the second file, where `NR` is now larger than `FNR`)

You even can expand this to per-file specifications of lines to be skipped:

```
awk -- '--skip<=0' person1.txt skip=7 file1.txt skip=4 file2.txt >result.txt
```

You would then simply precede each file name with a variable assignment that sets the `awk` variable `skip` to the number of lines you want to have skipped from the respective input file. The `awk` program checks for each processed line whether this variable, if decremented by 1, falls below zero, which would indicate that the number of lines to be skipped has been reached. The condition would then be `true`, and the current line printed.

Notice that the `--` "end-of-options" specifier is needed because the first command of the actual program starts with a `--`.

Comment: Using `awk` is my preferred method for this too, although I'd just do `( cat person1.txt; awk 'NR > 7' file1.txt ) > result.txt`.

Comment: @JivanPal That's also rather compact, however, in that case I would recommend `{ cat person1.txt; awk 'NR>7' file1.txt; } > result.txt` instead to avoid the extra sub-shell.

Comment: @AdminBee what's the benefit of avoiding the extra subshell? Just avoiding the overhead of launching one? Could that be significant on any modern system? Embedded perhaps? Or simply a general principle of efficiency: "don't use more resources than actually needed"?

Comment: @terdon As you correctly assumed, the resource overhead in most cases doesn't really matter. However, I consider it good practice not getting too cozy with (possibly nested) sub-shells, because this may have you end up with problems where the scope/lifetime of settings is limited to your sub-shell and you wonder why your main script doesn't seem to notice the settings.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done with `sed`

The steps are to delete the first 6 lines. When you get to the 7th you need to read in the other file and then delete the 7th line.

```
sed '1,6d
7{
r person1.txt
d
} ' file1.txt > newfile1.txt &&
mv newfile1.txt file1.txt
```

Some versions of `sed` have a `-i` flag to do an "in place" edit.

Another way is to use `tail`.

```
{
    cat person1.txt
    tail -n +8 file1.txt
} > newfile1.txt && mv -f newfile1.txt file1.txt
```

Here the two commands are put together and the output redirected together.

Comment: Or `sed -e 7rfile2 -e 1,7d`

Answer (score 4):

```
$ ed file1
1,7d
0r person1
w
q
```

Or, as a script:

```
ed -s file1 <<'EOF'
1,7d
0r person1
w
q
EOF
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' 1,7d '0r person1' w q | ed -s file1
```

Nowadays, `ex` (being installed with `vi`) is more common than `ed`, although both are specified in POSIX and the latter is simpler.  For real-world portability, just replace `ed` with `ex` in the code samples.